# Sort divs in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I new in Django, help in my problem, please.

```
class Article(models.Model):
articlecategory = models.ForeignKey(ArticleCategory)
```

Articlecategory can by Big_news(1 news in a row) or Small_news(3 news in a row)

I want this logic in template:

- 1)sort all article by date
- 2)if last 3 news = Small_news => create
  row with 3 div
- 3)if in last 3 news we have Big_news => create row
  with Big_news-> then create row with small news(if all 3 news after big_news are small_news)

How can I get this(paragraph 3) in Django?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this logic in your view. It doesn't belong in your template.

```
class ArticleRowViewModel:
    def __init__(self, articles):
        self.articles = articles

    def is_big_news(self):
        return len(self.articles) == 1

articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-date')
previous_articles = []
view_models = []
for article in articles:
    if article.big_news:
        # TODO: I don't know if this is right.
        # Your business logic didn't cover it. I'm treating it if there
        # any small news articles, that they should appear as such before
        # the current big `article` in the loop.
        if previous_articles:
            view_models.append(ArticleRowViewModel(previous_articles))
            previous_articles = []
        view_models.append(ArticleRowViewModel([article]))
    else:
        previous_articles.append(article)
        # Check if we have 3 small articles.
        if len(previous_articles) == 3:
            view_models.append(ArticleRowViewModel(previous_articles))
            previous_articles = []  
render_or_something(view_models)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i have list example: 0 - small news; 1 - big news [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 , 0, 0, 0]. What i need in template? I want <row>1</row>; <row> <div>0</div><div>0</div><div>0</div></row> . I try forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 but it did not work well for my list. How can i get forloop.counter only for small news?